# Как найти данные через фильтр (NameTabl.objects.filter(nameCol="Вася")) в БД?

Tags: база-данных, django, postgresql, filter

Использую Django 1.11.
Имеется БД PostgreSQL с таблицей в которой имеются данные.
При запросе `NameTabl.objects.filter(nameCol="Вася")` с точно существующими данными по этому запросу выдается `QeruSet[]` с огромным количеством лишних данных, а нужного найти не могу.
Как правильно сипользовать фильтры, что бы полученный результат записался в переменную?

Comment: `QuerySet[]` с огромным количеством лишних данных - это как?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev когда отвечал на ваш вопрос, то понял где у меня ошибка) Спасибо за помощь! ) Ошибка была в том, что у меня вместо `"Вася"` искались не корректные данные.